# how to get only date from string?

Tags: ios4

how to get only date from datetime date value
my code is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];   
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

lblDateAvailable.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[datepick date]];
NSDate *date=[dateFormat dateFromString:lblDateAvailable.text];
NSLog(@"%@",date);

result=2012-08-17 18:30:00 +0000
```

i want to get only date from string.so plz suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Date into string and using this method Separated the component and pass the Separated value in your label.

```
NSArray* components = [yourdatestring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```